# inconsistency when converting to string in HmacSHA256 in Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I want to comment on the following problem I have. I am creating a token in IONIC which for this I use the CryptoJS library. at the time of creating the signature, it gives me a totally different number than what I expect. the signature I expect is lLJuDJVb4DThZq / yP4fgYOk / 14d3piOvlSuWEI / E7po = and the one that gives me the method is the following: 94b26e0c955be034e166aff23f87e060e93fd78777a623af952b96108fc4ee9a
I have read the documentation and I think I'm missing something but I can not catch it. I leave the code below:

```
GenerarToken(data)
```

{

```
let datos:string = btoa(JSON.stringify(data));

let encabezado:string = btoa(JSON.stringify({
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}));

let unido:string = encabezado +  "." + datos;

var llave = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(unido, key).toString();
let token = unido + '.' + llave;

return token;
```

}

with respect to the header and payload I agree well, I only have the problem when creating the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting a base64-encoded output, but are getting hex output because that's the default. Try passing the encoding:

```
var llave = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(unido, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Documented at https://github.com/jakubzapletal/crypto-js#the-hasher-output

Comment: Thank you very much, it was what I was missing. now if both signatures are the same